# How to filter strings in apex?

Tags: apex, aura

I am writing a code that filters records who has the value of 2 fields**(Firstname__c,Lastname__c)** concatenation. I assigned that concatenation value in a string and I use **contains method** . But it returns nothing. Will you help me implement this code ?. for example this line of code will return  String **[SELECT Id,First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Ticket_Number__c  FROM Ticket__c WHERE Event__c =:Event]** an array values of {firstname:martin lastname:johnson,firstname:marvin lastname: jhon,firstname:peter lastname:blair}.Using this code  **String fullname = String.valueOf(obj.First_Name__c)+' '+String.valueOf(obj.Last_Name__c);** it will concatenate the firstname and lastname values. then my **Searchkey** variable contains **"MA"** .. it will filter and assigned the ticket_number__c of **(martin and marvin)** into the **List filtered**  by this code **filtered.add(obj.Ticket_Number__c);**

HERE IS MY CODE

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static List<Ticket__c> SAETH(String Searchkey,String Event){
    List<String> filtered = new List<String>();
    for(Ticket__c obj : [SELECT Id,First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Ticket_Number__c  FROM Ticket__c WHERE Event__c =:Event])
    {
        String fullname = String.valueOf(obj.First_Name__c)+' '+String.valueOf(obj.Last_Name__c);
        if(fullname.contains(Searchkey))
        {
            filtered.add(obj.Ticket_Number__c);
        }
    }
    System.debug(filtered);
    return [SELECT Id, Name, Event_Product__c,First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Ticket_Number__c, (SELECT Id, Check_In__c, Check_Out__c, Status__c FROM Ticket_Logs__r  ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1 )  FROM Ticket__c t WHERE Ticket_Number__c IN:filtered];
}
```

Comment: can u add some example data that u hv used and what u see in the debug logs, and why don't you use SOSL FIND to search https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm

Comment: Wouldn't there normally be a space between the first name and the last name?

Comment: read my post again i update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you should be using `containsIgnoreCase()` instead of `contains` for your case. Should be working for you.

Comment: you right :) thankyou ... you got it !!!!!